# Openfire server, multiple connection, route.all-resources doesn't work

Tags: resources, chat, openfire, strophe

We use `http-bind` with BOSH and Openfire (3.8.2) as backend and Strophe library (JS) on frontend for our chat application.

Every user gets a specified unique resource by connection. That means, that a user can be logged in different devices/browsers at once (multiple connection, e.g `user@example.com/resource1`, `user@example.com/resource2` etc.). Ideally, we want messages to be sent to all connected resources.

We set `route.all-resources setting="true"` and the connection priority is equal for all user resources, but behavior hasn't changed at all (chat messages received only last connected user resource).

Could anybody suggest solutions or ideas to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It also depend on the client, if the client explicitly send the message to only one resource, then only that resource will get it. If you send the message without it you should be able to get the message in both resources.

Answer (score 2):

You may need either `route.all-resources` or `route.really-all-resources`

`route.really-all-resources` = `true` will send message to all sessions with a non-negative priority
`route.all-resources` = `true` will send messages to all sessions ***that share the highest*** non-negative priority

The source for this is at https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire/blob/master/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/spi/RoutingTableImpl.java#L567