# Xmpp, Strophe Js : Multiple active connections for same user

Tags: ios, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I have implemented web chat using xmpp + openfire + strophe. On the same openfire and xmpp server we have developed IOS chat as well.

**I am facing below problem.**

Lets say a user A connected in xmpp in IOS app and user A chat with user B.
Now same user A connect with web chat to xmpp using strophe and user B sends the message to user A then User A will have message in the web chat connection only.

Now user A connect with xmpp in IOS and User B send message then User A will get message in IOS app only, not in web chat.

Is it possible then user A will have message at all the connections which are created?

Does it possible a User will have multiple xmpp connections and all the connections are able to send message to another user and able to get messages at all the connections of the user?

Can you please help me to solve this issue in Strophe Js and IOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage it by setting different **RESOURCES** (https://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Jabber_Resources).
Each device must declare a different Resource ("myPc", "android", "iphone", "ipad", "Spark", it's just an arbitrary String).

Openfire must be configurated to manage multiple Resources (Server -> Server Settings -> Resource Policy).

EDIT: Openfire has also a priority-based delivery system that chooses the highest priority resource and send only to it the message.
(a nice discussion: https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/53377)
Enable by setting the property:

```
route.all-resources
```

to

```
true
```

According to this question, you need also
[Openfire server, multiple connection, route.all-resources doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396169/openfire-server-multiple-connection-route-all-resources-doesnt-work)

```
route.really-all-resources
```

setted to

```
true
```

**HOW TO DO:**

- by database, adding on "ofProperty" table both properties
- or by openfire web client -> Server -> Server Manager -> System
  Property (add in on bottom of the page).

Keep in mind that

1. **Presence** has a priority (a number between -128 and 128), default
   it's 1. Carefully change this number.
2. Of course clients must **not** include the resource while sending a
   message (it's your case but pay attention to keep the right
   behaviour)

I'm sorry about but I don't know how to assign a Resource name in Strophe.js as I see in some examples, programmers just add it manually as string concat  (`user@server/resource` while login)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had  connected by two different resources in xmpp through strophe but messages are only received on the latest connections only. I want to receive and send messages on each connections of same user. Does it possible?

Comment: What about openfire? Wich option did you selected? However check about how you add listener in your clients, maybe it's only about you miss the listener due a miss of a condition while creating a chat

Comment: In the openfire "Server -> Server Settings -> Resource Policy" in this page I have selected option "Never Kick".

Comment: For chat I am using gab js with strophe js. And I am passing unique resource at every connections like user@host/unique-resource. But only recent connection is able to receive messages from opponent user. I have need like all the connections should receive messages.

Comment: Lets say openfiren username is "rahul" and host is "example.com".
Connection 1 : rahul@example.com/res-1
Connection 2: rahul@example.com/res-2
After second connection I am able to get messages in second connection only. And if I am sending message from first connection then will get messages in first connection not able to receive messages in second connection. Will receive messages in second connection only after send messages from it again. How I can able to receive messages in both connections at a time?

Comment: @RahulPatel don't worry, it's clear. I will update my answer. You miss also a property of openfire (https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/53377 for a complete explanation)