# Support multiple windows for a single user - XMPP chat using strophe.js

Tags: xmpp, strophe

I have a chat client that can be incorporated into multiple hosts, the chat client is independent.

User A logs in at two places - say chrome and firefox

So User A sends Message User B, User B receives the message, chat message is displayed at both sides.

Now User A has logged in at the window in the separate browser also, I want to push the message and display the message here also

Just like if you open a Gmail chat window at multiple browsers, then the sent message is pushed at both the ends.

Answer (score 0):

XMPP protocol define JID as following:

> JIDs consist of three main parts:
>
> The node identifier (optional) The domain identifier (required) The
>   resource identifier (optional) JIDs are encoded UTF-8. A grammar will
>   be presented first, followed by specific clarifying and further
>   restricting remarks.

or in s simpler language you JID is built from:
Username@YourDomain.com/Resource

one user can have many resources, 
for example:

- prashantsahni@domain.com/phone
- prashantsahni@domain.com/firefox
- prashantsahni@domain.com/chrome

just set up the right resource for the user each time and let the XMPP Server to take care of the rest.

[and you can look at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636127/xmpp-strophe-js-multiple-active-connections-for-same-user) to see how to do it with strophe

tou can read more about it in here:
https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0029.html

Comment: bhai question aap samajh nahi paaye

Answer (score 0):

I am using message carbon.
There is a plugin provided by strophe. - strophe carbon

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented using message carbons. The XEP is given [here](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html). For this to work you will need to check if the server supports this XEP. Most servers, Ejabberd, MongooseIM, Openfire, etc., supports the extension. The server will forward the message carbon to each resource. Once you have enabled message carbons in your server, all you need is to take care of the stanza which is being forwarded to you from each resource for a JID.

Lets say the JID for user A and user B is userA@domain.com and userB@domain.com, and you login to both chrome and firefox using the full JIDs below:

- userA@domain.com/chrome
- userA@domain.com/firefox

Now when you start sending message to user B from chrome, the message will be sent to your XMPP server which then also forwards the same message to your firefox browser. Lets say if the original message stanza sent from chrome is as follows:

```
<message xmlns='jabber:client'
     from='userA@domain.com/chrome'
     to='userB@domain.com'
     type='chat'>
 <body>What man art thou that, thus bescreen'd in night, so stumblest on my counsel?</body>
  <thread>0e3141cd80894871a68e6fe6b1ec56fa</thread>
</message>
```

You should receive the forwarded stanza in your firefox as follows:

```
 <message xmlns='jabber:client'
         from='userA@domain.com'
         to='userA@domain.com/firefox'
         type='chat'>
  <received xmlns='urn:xmpp:carbons:2'>
    <forwarded xmlns='urn:xmpp:forward:0'>
      <message xmlns='jabber:client'
               from='userA@domain.com/chrome'
               to='userB@domain.com'
               type='chat'>
        <body>What man art thou that, thus bescreen'd in night, so stumblest on my counsel?</body>
        <thread>0e3141cd80894871a68e6fe6b1ec56fa</thread>
      </message>
    </forwarded>
  </received>
</message>
```

You need to extract original message from the forwarded stanza. Also note that you can use each browser tab as a separate resource. You might also want to configure the maximum number of resources the server can handle at a time for a user.